# Why can't I make a face from these vertices?

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces

I made a shape with bezier curves, then converted it to a mesh, then extruded it along one axis. I can't remember which end is the original at this point. I selected all the vertices on one end and use F (in Edit Mode) to make a face with all the selected vertices. Then I went to the other end and selected all the vertices on that end to do the same thing. When I press F, something happens, but it's hard to see just what. It looks like when I press F to add the face, that some of the lines that run from end to end change to orange and when I undo that, they change back. Even when I've zoomed in, it's hard to see just what is happening.

I select the vertices in x-ray mode, to be sure I get them all, then I change to solid mode before creating the face, so I'll see the new face.

Here is the full object with the vertices at one end all selected:
[image]

Here is a closer look of just the end where I'm trying to make a new face:
[image]

(Blend file is here: [image])

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: @Chris Done. Been so long since I posted I forgot about that. Thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

1. in edit mode press A X -> only faces
2. then press M -> 0.01 (Merge by distance)
3. then select your upper vertices again and press F

result:

[image]

Comment: It works!

Any idea why it worked differently on one end than on the other? (Oddly, now that I'm looking at it, I only seem to see the face on the other end from some angles and not others.)

Comment: i tried - for me it worked on both sides. Maybe turn of x-ray mode?

Comment: Ah - it might have something to do with me not using x-ray mode the first time through and the way I selected vertices at the time.